# .net MVC IdentityDbContext Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I'm creating a new MVC 5 project with the templated Asp.Identity implementation. What I'd like to do is make use of the existing Asp.Identify implementation within my own domain entities For example a Asp.Identity User can be a member of 1 or more Clubs. I'd like to be able to access User info in my MVC controllers - for example I'd like to be able to see if user is part of a specific role or not etc..

Basically I am still a little confused on a number of issues which I'd like clarification.

In the Startup.Auth.cs the ApplicationUserManager and its associated Entity framework DBContext is added. i.e.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

1. Will this Entity framework DBContext be added to every MVC Controller - is this done via dependency injection?
2. If its injected with an IOC - is it created on a per-HTTP-request?

I extend the existing templated ApplicationDbContext by adding my own Domain entities to it (as below). 
3. Will I be able to access these all in the MVC Controillers and again is it per-request?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
  {
  }

  public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
  {
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
  }

//Add my own domain entities here...
  public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title. So far it's just a lit of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, this is created for each request.  The method name is called `CreatePerOwinContext()` so it is creating this `ApplicationDbContext` each time an `OwinContext` is created (on each request).
2. No, this is not dependency injection per se.  This is the Owin context creating a new context and holding it in the Owin Bootstrapper for the life of the request.  This works in a similar way to many Dependency Injection containers in that it controls the lifetime of the object, but this does not by itself do injection and it will not inject the context by itself into your controllers or whatever.
3. Yes, you can access these in the controllers by using `Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplciationDbContext>()`.  Since it is returning an ApplicationDbContext, you can do anything you can do with An ApplicationDbContext.  So if you extend it, so too will those extended properties be available.

If you want to do DI with a container with Owin, you need a DependencyResolver that is Owin aware.  Most of the containers provide one for their injection.  For instance, Ninject provides the Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost nuget package, which allows you to use `app.UseNinjectMiddleware()` configuration

Comment: Thanks Erik - just to clarify. If I want to be able to access the ApplicationDBContext (Entity framework dbcontext) in my MVC Controllers I dont need to inject them in with an IOC (dependency injection framework) because it will already be there via the CreatePerOwinContext() method. Is this correct? And is this 'correct\good' practice?

Comment: @gisWeeper - I didn't say any of that, not sure where you got that impression.  I answered your questions, I made no recommendation about whether it was correct or what you needed to do.  You simply asked if it was dependency injection, I said it was not. I said you *CAN* access them in your controller via the GetOwinContext, not that this was the right or best way.  That does not mean you shouldn't inject them.  MVC doesn't provide injection by itself (at least not in the current version).

Comment: Apologies Erik - I jumped the gun with that one.

Comment: I found this link good at explaining: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/owincontext-and-why-you-can-have-many-of-them/

Comment: @gisWeeper - Yes, however he refers to it as DI when it's really not.. and he kind of corrects himself but is rather confusing about it.  It's really more of a service locator with a factory